# r shiny renderUI in a loop

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to output several tables as a one uiOutput. If I put them together in a list using a loop then all outputs are equal to the last one.
Example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tables")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    data=array(rnorm(150),c(10,5,3))

    tfc = function(m){
#      x = m[1,1]
      renderTable({m})
    }

    result=list()
    for(i in 1:3)
      result[[i]] = tfc(data[,,i])

    return(result)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I remove the commented line (x = m[1,1]) I get the desired result.

I can live with this workaround but is there a reason why shiny behaves like that or is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use `lapply` for such usecases. This way, you don't run into issues with lazy evaluation.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tables")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    data=array(rnorm(150),c(10,5,3))

    tfc = function(m){renderTable({m})}

    lapply(1:3, function(i){tfc(data[,,i])})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you want to use a reacive table, you can use something like

```
tfc = function(m, output, id){
  output[[id]] <- renderTable({m()})
  tableOutput(id)
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

To get around this, you can [`force`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/force.html) evaluation of function arguments:

```r
tfc = function(m) {
  force(m)
  renderTable(m)
}
```

or

create a [`local`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) scope for each loop iteration:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  local({
    i <- i
    result[[i]] <<- tfc(data[,,i])
  })
}
```

`lapply` works as well, but only for R versions 3.2 and above: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.2.0/NEWS.R-3.2.0.html