# Shiny navbarPage keeps showing "tab-pane active"

Tags: r, shiny

Here is the code to a simple Shiny app:

*UI*

```
    library(shiny)
    shareholders.list <- c("Investor A", "Investor B")
    tmp.label.select.inv <- "Select one or multiple investors:"
    shinyUI(navbarPage(    
      title = "App",
      titlePanel(title = "TITLE"),
      tabPanel("Tab 1"             
        , sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              style = "font-family: 'Segoe UI';
                       color: #FFFFFF;
                       background: #014d92;",
              selectInput("tmp.IDs", 
                label = tmp.label.select.inv,      
                choices = union("All", shareholders.list),
                multiple = T,
                width = 245
               ), 
               actionButton("select.all", 
                 em("Select / Deselect All"),
                 icon = icon("ok-sign", lib = "glyphicon"),
                 width = 245,
                 style="color: #000000; 
                       background: #FFFFFF; 
                       border-color: #000000"
                ),       
                width = 2                
              ),                           
              mainPanel(                
                h5(em("Chosen Investors: "), 
                br(),strong(textOutput("selected_tmp.IDs"))),
                br(),br(),
                tableOutput("table_tmp.IDs")
              ),      
              position = "left"      
            )
          )    
          , tabPanel("Download Tables",
              mainPanel(
                textOutput("odd_even_select.all")
            ))   
            , selected = "Tab 1"
          )
        )
```

*Server*

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        output$selected_tmp.IDs <- renderText({
          paste0(input$tmp.IDs)
        })

    })
```

The problem is that the app keeps displaying "tab-pane active tab-5966-1
" on both tabs.

Any idea how to fix it?

## Edit:

I have edited the code and added more details in order to be replicable (note that the unwanted display in the above instance now states "tab-25-25-1" - c.f. image below).

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce any runtime-issues since your example has syntax errors. There is no `titlePanel` argument in `navbarPage`

Comment: `titlePanel` might not be indicated in the `navbarPage` documentation, but I can assure you it works.

Comment: I an error message "`Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: titlePanel`" when I try to run your code as-is. Using `shiny-1.0.5`

Comment: Please try to create a minimal example that starts an app when your code is copy-pasted like, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46610753/r-shiny-renderui-in-a-loop)

Comment: @GregordeCillia I had to thin my code as my question had to much coding, that is why I tried to make it as short as possible. I believe however it should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you use the output of the function `shiny::titlePanel` as an argument of `navbarPage`. Here is a simpler app that basically leads to the same behavior

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    title = "app",
    titlePanel("Title"),
    tabPanel("Tab1", "content1"),
    tabPanel("Tab2", "content2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```

From the documentation of `?navbarPage`, it is clear that all unnamed arguments (`...`) should be `tabPanel` elements or strings.

> **`...`** tabPanel elements to include in the page. The navbarMenu function also accepts strings, which will be used as menu section headers. If the string is a set of dashes like "----" a horizontal separator will be displayed in the menu.

I don't know what you expect to happen when you put a `titlePanel` here. Do you want the title to show up in every tab or together with the `"app"` title?

Anyways, removing the `titlePanel` fixes the problem

```
shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    title = "app",
    tabPanel("Tab1", "content1"),
    tabPanel("Tab2", "content2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output){}
)
```

Comment: I wanted what the argument `header` in `navbarPage` produces. After switching to using this argument, the problem vanished. I haven't fully understood yet where exactly the code you provided differs from mine, but in any case you are right, `titlePanel` seems to have been the prolem.

Comment: The code I gave is almost exactly like yours, but shorter. I wrote it here so people who visit this question in the future will have an easier time reproducing the error and comparing it to their issues.